# Warnin:Illegal offset type [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2734] came on click of login in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I created a simple login form using Cake Php.When i click on the Login button one Warning appear

```
Illegal offset type [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2734
```

I have use link as a reference  http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/SeanCallan/2007/04/17/simple-form-authentication-in-1-2-x-x

Code of Login.ctp

### Login

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('username');?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('password');?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Login');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

2. modal file

find(array('username' => $data['username'], 'password' => md5($data['password'])), array('id', 'username'));
        if(empty($user) == false)
            return $user['User'];
        return false;
    }

}
?>

3.controller file

```
<?php 
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    var $name = "Users";
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
      var $components = array("Auth"); 
    function index()
    {

    }

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        $this->__validateLoginStatus();
    }

    function login()
    {
        if(empty($this->data) == false)
        {
            if(($user = $this->User->validateLogin($this->data['User'])) == true)
            {
                $this->Session->write('User', $user);
                $this->Session->setFlash('You\'ve successfully logged in.');
                $this->redirect('index');
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Sorry, the information you\'ve entered is incorrect.');
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->Session->destroy('user');
        $this->Session->setFlash('You\'ve successfully logged out.');
        $this->redirect('login');
    }

    function __validateLoginStatus()
    {
        if($this->action != 'login' && $this->action != 'logout')
        {
            if($this->Session->check('User') == false)
            {
                $this->redirect('login');
                $this->Session->setFlash('The URL you\'ve followed requires you login.');
            }
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Why that happened.i am new in this.Some developers in PHP chat room suggest me to not use that Cake PHP. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Well, the question is so detailed that the best answer I can come up with is that you did something wrong somewhere.

Comment: @SiGanteng  i have edited my question and that link i have used as reference

Comment: No implementation code.. no stacktrace.. vote to close.

Comment: @MikeB i will add the code please wait and don't do negative voting

Comment: @MikeB code is also there now ?

Comment: I surprised that why someone voting for to close the question very early.We can ask for the details if some has no details then you are right to close it

Comment: When you build your Form Inputs you will have to nest them into a model-parent-array that your post-data will look like this: $this->request->data['User']['username']

Answer (score 1):

Illegal offset type means that you tried to use an object or an array to index an array:

```
$x = stdClass;
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$a[$x]; // illegal offset type
```

Check your code for possible places where you've taken user input (which could be an array of values even though you thought it's just one value) and used it in some function that expected just a value.

If that Cake internal function expected a value and tried to use it as the offset of an array, this message would appear.

### Obs

The only place I notice in your code that passes a parameter (and not literal string values) is here:

```
$this->User->validateLogin($this->data['User']))
```

Do a **var_dump** on $this->data['User'] and see what's in it perhaps it's an array and you should've extracted just $this->data['User']['id'] I don't know, i haven't played that much with Cake.